# How do I allow custom screenOptions for Stack.Screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to add my own header options to Stack to simulate Native Stack like this

```
        <Stack.Screen name="FixedHeader"
            options={{
                title: "Fixed Header",
                headerRight: () => <HeaderButtons><ColorSchemeSwitchButton /></HeaderButtons>,
                headerLargeTitle: false, // this is not allowed
            }}
            component={FourthScreen}
        />
```

But TypeScript is throwing an error and I can't find a way of adding my new attribute into the screen options.

My workaround for the moment is

```
            options={{
                title: "Fixed Header",
                headerRight: () => <HeaderButtons><ColorSchemeSwitchButton /></HeaderButtons>,
                headerLargeTitle: false,
            } as StackNavigationOptions}
```

Comment: I believe that this is currently not supported by the navigation library. Check [this open Github issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8962). It might be possible to implement a [custom navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators/) and use this as a wrapper for the stack navigator, however I guess this is overkill for solving a typescript related problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Stack.Screen only accepts specific options only. If you want to pass additional attributes you can use [`initialParams`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#initial-params) props, which can be letter fetches in the screen using `route.params`.

```
<Stack.Screen 
  name="FixedHeader"
  options={{
      title: "Fixed Header",
      headerRight: () => <HeaderButtons><ColorSchemeSwitchButton /></HeaderButtons>,
  }}
  component={FourthScreen}
  initialParams={{ headerLargeTitle: false }} // you can pass here
/>
```

Comment: the problem with that approach is route params now contains information that is not route related.

Comment: So can you please explain how you want to use `headerLargeTitle` ? If you want to use in `HeaderButtons` component then you can pass it as props.